# Error in gini {laeken}

Tags: r, variance, confidence-interval

I'm trying to estimate the variances for gini coefficients in R using `laeken` package. Here is my code:

```
c1 <- gini("LIFPRTNR", weights="weight3var", design="stratvar", cluster="panelvar", years="time3group", breakdown="RSEX", data=Concentration, var = "bootstrap", bootType = "naive", seed = 1234)
```

I keep getting the error

```
Error in rownames<-(*tmp*, value = c("lower", "upper")) : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
```

Do I need to convert the column in the dataframe to a list?

Comment: What are the dimensions of "Concentration"?

Comment: dim(Concentration) [1] 45669     6